# How to distinct dupulicate nodes on orientdb?

Tags: orientdb

I executed code below.

```
select expand(both()) from data
where value = '123456'
```

There are two nodes (node_A, node_B) whose value equals '123456'
and both of them connected with node_C and node_D.

Finally it returned node_C and node_D for several times
but I just want each of them for one time.

I tried to use distinct() around "expand(both())" but failed.

How can I distinct dupulicate nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select expand(distinct(@rid)) from (select expand(both()) from data
where value = '123456')
```

Comment: It throws error when inside select returns no records.

How can I make OrientDB avoid null?